# Подключение UnitPay к сайту

Tags: php

Уже неделю сижу над этим подключением. Не как не могу понять в чём проблема, всё скопировал с документации. Вот код:

```
    <?php

session_start();
$secretKey = 'тут он есть, я просто его убрал';
$publicKey = '407129-78572';

$errors = array();
$account = '';
$currency = 'RUB';
$desc = 'Покупка внутриигровой валюты';
$count = '';
$price = '';
$sum = '';
$signature = '';

if (!isset($_POST['count']) || trim($_POST['count']) == "") {
    array_push($errors, 'Необходимо заполнить поле "Количество"');
}

if (!is_numeric($_POST['count'])) {
    array_push($errors, 'Поле "Количество" должно быть числом');
}

if (!isset($_POST['price']) || trim($_POST['price']) == "") {
    array_push($errors, 'Неудалось определить цену');
}

if (!isset($_POST['publicKey'])) {
    array_push($errors, 'Не удалось определить ID магазина');
}

if ($publicKey != $_POST['publicKey']) {
    array_push($errors, 'Подмена публичного ключа');
}

if (count($errors)) {
    echo generateResponse('error', $errors, false);
    exit();
}


$account = $_SESSION['minecraft'];
$currency = $_POST['currency'];
$desc .= ' для ' . $account;

$count = $_POST['count'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$sum = $price * $count;

$signature = getFormSignature($account, $currency, $desc, $sum, $secretKey);
$url = 'https://unitpay.money/pay/' . $publicKey . '/card?sum=' . $sum . '&account=' . $account . '&currency=' . $currency . '&desc=' . $desc . '&signature=' . $signature;

echo generateResponse('success', false, $url);
exit();


function getFormSignature($account, $currency, $desc, $sum, $secretKey) {
    $hashStr = $account.'{up}'.$currency.'{up}'.$desc.'{up}'.$sum.'{up}'.$secretKey;
    return hash('sha256', $hashStr);
}

function generateResponse($status, $msg, $url)
{
    return json_encode(array(
        'status'    =>  $status,    // success/error
        'msg'       =>  $msg,       // if error
        'redirect'  =>  $url,       // if success
    ));
}
```

вот скрин того, что не работает:
[image: Вот скрин того, что не работает:]

Comment: Использовали бы их официальный [SDK](https://github.com/unitpay/php-sdk)

Comment: оно не работает, я пробовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я всё решил кардинально. Просто написал в поддержку и мне отключили подписи.